# Why doesn't IO#seek work for TCPSocket?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I wrote some simple code to learn the structure of a TCPSocket. I thought it's like an IO stream so I tried to use `seek` to move the "reading position" back a byte:

```
socket.gets #=> hello world
socket.seek(-5, IO::SEEK_CUR)
socket.gets #=> hello world # this should return world
```

but, it gives me an error:

```
server.rb:11:in `seek': Illegal seek (Errno::ESPIPE)
```

Does anyone have an idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

If this was the case then the socket needs to keep all data around if someone would decides to seek backwards (and how would forward seek work, block for more data?). You could probably quite easy write a wrapper class around a socket that keeps track of a position and also buffers all data or blocks if needed etc.

But maybe you could try to use [IO#bytes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-each_byte) or [IO#chars](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-each_char) in combination with [Enumerator#peek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek)?

Comment: Forward seek would obviously use tachyons to find out what was going to be downloaded in the future.

Answer (score 1):

TCP/IP would be more like having a series of files on disk, where you can only read forward a file at a time. The files have to be read sequentially, and you can't jump ahead or back. It's not capable of random I/O, like you can do on a disk, it's more like a serial connection you can only read as things appear.

In order to do what you want you have to build a buffer, where you append each block (i.e., file), reconstructing the entire message. If you want to look backwards at any point, you have to look in your buffer. If you want to look forward you have to wait for that block to be received and read and appended.

That's a simple explanation. It's possible to request blocks be resent in IP but really, at the level we normally work at, we're only reading forward.